# mysql database backup with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I want to backup my database using mysql dump. This is the code I run in Command prompt when the location is mysql bin.
`mysqldump -u root -pabc Db -r C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\ttttt.sql`
abc is the password. and I try to backup to a .sql file in desktop. I use mysql 5.5.
But the following error occured. `mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "and"`
But there is no table called 'and' in database and I didn't create such a table.But the error say about a 'and' table. How can I back up mysql database without this error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try instead:

```
mysqldump -u root -pabc Db -r "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\ttttt.sql"
```

Your command shell is breaking apart the pathname into multiple arguments. The quotes tell the shell to pass it all as a single argument to the `mysqldump` program.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. But Ealier the code I showed in my question worked well when the OS is Windows 7.But when I run the same, in windows XP, It didn't worked. I think there is something in OS as well.Your code worked well in XP .Thank you once again

Comment: It could be that Microsoft extended the shell to recognize this exact situation and spare you the quotes. But I'm not too familiar with newer Windows.

Answer (score 10):

I think there is some problem with syntax of command you are running. try something like this :

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbName > path\nameOfFile.sql
```

It will automatically ask for your password. You don't need to write it in command.