# How do I create a .jar with a databse?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I have a java app (using Netbeans) and a SQL database that is being used by the app. By using the 'Clean and Build Project' from Netbeans it creates a .jar executable file.

But the problem is: Whenever I try to run the project on a machine that doesn't have the database created, the app does not contain the database.

How do I do this? How do I do so that I can run it from one .jar file that will 'include' the database?

Comment: What database? Embedded? Standalone? It matters.

Comment: I don't know what's the diffrence, but my connection between the app and the DB is only the Connect.
I'm guessing Standalone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL then create a dump file for your database table and import that dump file to create database/table in the target machine, then you can run your program without any hassle.
Check this link: [mysql database backup with mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200076/mysql-database-backup-with-mysqldump)

Comment: I did this, however, upon trying to create the database in another machine it returns: Connection Refused error, does the target machine need to have MySQL installed to be able to have a database created in it?

Comment: yes, it requires mysql installed in it before importing sql dump file

Comment: Is there anyway to create the database on the target machine whitout requiring that machine to have MySQL installed?
Like with a simple executable or something?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051686/how-to-run-mysql-on-windows-without-having-to-install